# Xampp Mercury Localhost Outlook 2010 Not Working

Tags: email, xampp, localhost, outlook-2010, mercury-mta

Environment: Windows 7-64 Ultimate, Xampp 3.2.1, Mercury, Outlook 2010.

I have gone through a few tutorials on how to set up Xampp Mercury for Localhost email functions using outlook Express as the test email app. The ultimate purpose is to test PHP/email functions.

I have set up Mercury as per the tutorial on:  http://noobcode.blogspot.ca/2010/01/how-to-send-mail-from-localhost-with.html.  Got to the point of setting up Outlook - except I have Outlook 2010, not Express.  Used the same settings, but Outlook 2010 gave me an error message during the setup/test stage.

The error message I get from Outlook 2010 during the setup and test stage is:  "Send test email message:  Cannot send the message.  Verify the e-mail address in your account properties.  The server responded:  421 Service not available, closing channel."

Is there a difference between using outlook express and outlook 2010 for this purpose?

Several screenshots of what I did are provided at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jkit8i41lhicsuq/ULlWLcJcu6

Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: Just tried the same with Mozilla Thunderbird and I seem to get a similar error.

Comment: Did the exact same setup and configuration on another "cleaner" machine and it works fine... Confirms that the Tutorial and settings are OK. just need to find out what is causing failure on this windows machine (has tons more applications on it).

Answer (score 0):

Re-installed the latest Xampp and Mercury, reconfigured as before, and now it works fine. On various discussions over the web, it seemed others were having similar issues, where a re-install or update solved the problem.  This route worked for me.